# Extract matching patterns from a string

Tags: r, regex

My data:

```
d1 <- "GET /api/dir/100%ABC/user/prints/abcd1111/file"
d2 <- "GET /api/dir/100%ABC/prints/efgh1111/file"
```

I want to extract the string:`user/prints` or `prints` part from my data.
I know how to extract between 2 certain strings like:

```
str_extract(d1, "(?<=/dir/)(.*)(?=%ABC)")
```

to get the number `100`.

How to extract after `%ABC/` and end with `prints`(contains `prints`) so I can get :`user/prints` or `prints` from same script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In base R, we can use `sub` to extract everything after `"%ABC"` till `"prints"`.

```
sub(".*%ABC/(.*prints).*", "\\1", d1)
#[1] "user/prints"

sub(".*%ABC/(.*prints).*", "\\1", d2)
#[1] "prints"
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly elegant, but this should do:

```
paste0(str_extract(d1, "(?<=%ABC)(.*)(?=prints)"),"prints")
# [1] "/user/prints"
paste0(str_extract(d2, "(?<=%ABC)(.*)(?=prints)"),"prints")
# [1] "/prints"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub` from `base R`

```
gsub(".*ABC/|/\\w+/\\w+$", "", d1)
#[1] "user/prints"
gsub(".*ABC/|/\\w+/\\w+$", "", d2)
#[1] "prints"
```